# Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles in Server 2008/Windows 7

Tags: .net, azman

I am trying to follow [these instructions](http://tonesdotnetblog.wordpress.com/2010/02/26/how-to-use-asp-net-membership-and-role-providers-with-adlds-adam-with-code/) on how to use AD LDS for both Membership and Roles for an application.  I've almost got it all set, but the ending code calls for the "IAzApplication2" object from Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles.

I can see how to install it in Server 2003, but I cannot find out how to install it and/or implement it in Server 2008. In fact, my server doesn't seem to be able to reference the Microsoft.Interop Namespace at all.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to get to the IAzApplication2(+) object?  Am I missing a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer you're looking for is here: [Where is microsoft.interop.security.azroles on Server 2008 R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726594/where-is-microsoft-interop-security-azroles-on-server-2008-r2)  (but to save you clicking, it's in the GAC in 32-bit and 64-bit forms).